# Split Python list

Tags: python, python-3.x

I got a list in Python:

```
['Some', 'text', ':', 'And', 'some', 'other', 'text']
```

I want a function that will split the list before the `:`, e.g:

```
['Some text :', 'And some other text'].
```

What's the best way to achieve this? Thanks for your time.

Comment: `"".join([Some, text, :, And, some, other, text]).split(":")`

Comment: will there be only one `:` in the list?

Comment: Yes, in my current use case only one `:`

Comment: @bilke That isn't correct Python syntax and wouldn't/doesn't produce the correct output regardless

Comment: This is either not actual python or not a [mcve]

Comment: @bilke have you tried to run the code you proposed?

Comment: @NickM is that a list of strings of a string representation of a list?

Comment: @AlainT. you are correct, fixed

Comment: Find the index of `':'`, and then use join to assemble the two parts of the list into individual strings: `i=lst.index(':')` `result = [" ".join(lst[:i+1]), " ".join(lst[i+1:])`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this:

```
lst = ['Some', 'text', ':', 'And', 'some', 'other', 'text']

ans  = " ".join(lst).split(":")
ans[0], ans[1] = ans[0]+":", ans[1].lstrip()

print(ans)
```

output:
`['Some text :', 'And some other text']`